# I need a list of MacOS app startup locations

Tags: macos, startup

A year or so ago, I set up (under Sierra) a shell script I wrote to launch automatically using the conditions that it required "network availability" and was to trigger on external drive mounting by editing a plist file in Xcode.

Unfortunately, I can't remember the name or location of this file and I need to temporarily disable the configured auto-launch.  Can anyone identify this file or at least provide me a list of app startup locations to check?

Comment: Apparently, Yes. It was in /Library/LaunchAgents,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `launchd`, the plist locations will be as follows:

- `${HOMEDIR}/Library/LaunchAgents` - single user launch agent
- `/Library/LaunchAgents` - all users launch agent
- `/Library/LaunchDameons` - system daemons (runs as root)

To see what is being loaded, issue the command:

```
sudo launchctl list
```