# How to stop the Anydesk application from opening at startup?

Tags: macos, mac, login-items

I utilize this application called Anydesk for remote desktop very frequently, and while I was recently removing programs from starting up at login (because I wanted a faster start up speed) I noticed that Anydesk wasn't in the list of login items, even though it shows up whenever I login after I restart/shut down the computer.

How does one rectify this issue?

I am running OSX El Capitan on a 13" MacBook Pro.

Comment: Have you asked the developer of Anydesk how to remove their app from startup?  Maybe they have an application support forum?

Comment: Also check in the Preferences of the app for any kind of check box for "Start at login" or similar to like that.

Comment: See this related question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305134/i-need-a-list-of-macos-app-startup-locations/305189#305189

Answer (score 65):

After several attempts I finally found the file that is created during the installation process. So to prevent AnyDesk from starting at login, you need to delete the file,

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Frontend.plist
```

[image]

That solved my issues with autostarting AnyDesk at login.

Comment: Something is weird here....
http://cubeupload.com/im/qcmptr/ScreenShot20180724at.png

Comment: Make sure it's /Library, not ~/Library (former is the system library, latter is your users' library folder)

Comment: On more recent versions it is `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Tray.plist`

Comment: On latest version (2022) it's `/Library/Daemons/com.philandro.anydesk.Helper.plist` and `/Library/Daemons/com.philandro.anydesk.service.plist`

Comment: On Ventura 13.5.1 2023 the file name is:
`/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk_ad_2d27ffa8.Frontend.plist`
my suggestion is to navigate to `/Library/LaunchAgents` and then find the plist file containing **anydesk** word

Answer (score 46):

I looked into the plist file (***/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Frontend.plist***) suggested in one of the answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331822/310671).

You can open the file using any text editor and change the lines:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

to

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

This worked for me.

Update for file path:
`/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Tray.plist`

For latest version, if the file is missing in the above path then check this file path:
`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.philandro.anydesk.service.plist`

Comment: On more recent versions it is `/Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Tray.plist`

Comment: The solution provided by @Abdullah above worked for me. However, I needed to **give myself (username) 'Read & Write' permissions for the 'LaunchAgents' directory** in order to edit the file, or else, it was asking to create a duplicate file and then edit it. Thanks a ton! AnyDesk really needs to fix this, because the solution is not always easy for an average user.

Comment: @DhananjayBhardwaj you can use [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370534/366024) to edit it

Answer (score 18):

Open your terminal and type this :

```
sudo plutil -replace RunAtLoad -bool false /Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Frontend.plist
```

Basically this will set the auto start boolean value in the *.plist file from `true` to `false` which as a result would disable the autostart function. It's practically the same thing as the above solutions but much simpler.

**User was on version 5.0.1 at the time of this answer.**

**Works on version 6.3.2**

Comment: See this comment: [On more recent versions it is /Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Tray.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326429/how-to-stop-the-anydesk-application-from-opening-at-startup/370534#comment451854_342821)

Answer (score 8):

For Windows users, you have to disable the application on startup and change the service startup type to manual.

For example on Windows 10 you should do the following:

1. Task Manager => Startup tab => right click on AnyDesk and change it to disable.
2. Control Panel => Administrative Tools => Services => AnyDesk Service => Right click and select properties => Startup type from [Automatic] to [Manual] => also you can press on stop button.

Next time when you want to start the application, windows will ask for permission (UAC) to start the AnyDesk service and also after quitting the application windows will ask for permission (UAC) to stop the service.

Comment: This answer addresses startup issues on Windows machines. The original question wanted information about macOS.

Comment: Ok, but Mr. Google throw us here anyway, so thank you for the answer +1.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items

Select AnyDesk, then press the minus button.

[image: macOS Login Items]

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to appear on my list: http://cubeupload.com/im/qcmptr/ScreenShot20180720at.png

Comment: @quantum.cmptr - this will sound silly, but try to add AD to the list and then (explicitly) remove it again - maybe even restart in between to register the entry!?

Comment: Alright, tried that, going to restart and see how it fares

Comment: @quantum.cmptr so what happened?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me since AnyDesk was not listed in my system preferences login programs.

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: what do I even do with this? Save it in a txt file at my desktop? :(
If it is a thankyou comment, it is not an answer. Don't just copy content from other users' answers and post it as their own.

Answer (score -1):

try this command

```
sudo rm /Library/LaunchAgents/com.philandro.anydesk.Frontend.plist
```